# Computational complexity of arithmetic in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$

Tags: computer-science, finite-fields, computational-complexity

What is the computational complexity (in terms of big $O()$ notation) of arithmetic in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ or alternatively is there a good reference?

I am interested in the asymptotic computational complexity of addition, multiplication and  inverse.

Comment: Relevant keyword: [Optimal normal basis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X8890090X).

Comment: You have a choice here: fast addition with slow multiplication - or fast multiplication with slow addition.

Comment: Or even both fast, but requiring a lot of memory and precomputation.

Comment: What sort of complexity counts for you? Time vs. gate count? E.g. small fields could use a lookup table for multiplication. That has exponential gate complexity, but essentially constant time complexity.

Comment: Thinking of it, memory access times should scale with the logarithm of the capacity, so time complexity for exponentially-sized lookup tables would be $\operatorname{O}(n)$, not constant.

Comment: @ccorn It is the running time of an algorithm that I am interested in. So standard computational complexity.  I can't precompute a table as $2^k$ can be large in my case.

Answer (score 2):

With the caveat that you're probably asking the wrong question, general purpose methods for doing arithmetic with polynomials over finite fields tends to run directly parallel to integer methods; e.g. multiplication of large polynomials via Schönhage-Strassen and division by Barrett's algorithm and using newton's algorithm for inverses.

And general purpose computation in large finite fields is simply modular arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks.  In concrete terms, is each element represented as a polynomial of degree $k$ with coefficients that are $0$ or $1$?  And is multiplication simply polynomial multiplication modulo some polynomial of degree $k$?